# Connecting to Cloud SQL from docker container in compute engine

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to deploy a spring boot app within a docker container on compute engine and have it connect to a google cloud sql database. I've changed the IP address on the compute engine from dynamic to static and whitelisted the IP address in the cloud sql view however I still can't connect. 
I'm assuming the container has it's own IP address

Any suggestions?

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:579) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:603) ~[na:na]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
        ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this about [Connecting MySQL client using the Cloud SQL Proxy docker image](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-docker).There are both MySQL and  Postgresql and

There are some steps to confirm:

*Verify the scopes enabled on the instance
*Verify you are using the correct Instance Name:

> For example: myproject:us-central1:myinstance.

In case you are using other doc, please share it.